# Merging data to make a single curve

Tags: awk, sed, offset, data-analysis

```
1 0.832936
2 0.890475
3 0.816155
3 1.21183
4 1.21881
5 1.28013
6 1.28479
7 1.32075
8 1.39582
8 1.2462
9 1.24566
10 1.24029
11 1.30685
12 1.31264
13 1.38061
```

I want to combine the data to make it look like

```
1   0.832936
2   0.890475
3   0.816155
3   0.816155
4   0.823135
5   0.884455
6   0.889115
7   0.925075
8   1.000145
8   1.000145
9   0.999605
10  0.994235
11  1.060795
12  1.066585
13  1.134555
```

Here, I have used off-set of 0.3956 at $1=3 and substracting it till $1=8. Similarly, 0.2460 from $1=8 and extrapolating it to $1=13.

I have been using bash script using awk and sed to manipulate these data points to get desired output without any success so far. As I am new to it, It will take a while to get my head around this.

The current script looks like this:

```
for i in {1,5}
do
echo "For C_$i hist" 

awk -v i=$i '{   
    if(NR == i+2) p=0;p = $2;
    if(NR == i+3) n=0;n = $2;
    if(NR >= i+3 && NR <= i+8)
    print $1 " " ($2 - (n-p));
    }' Input >> Output
done
```

Can anyone here suggest any solution to automatize this calculation. Thanks in advance

Cheers, Mohit

Comment: Get rid of the shell loop and just use an awk script. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

perhaps more generic

```
$ awk 'p==$1 {d+=$2-p2} 
             {p=$1; p2=$2; printf "%d\t%.6f\n", $1, $2-d}' file

1       0.832936
2       0.890475
3       0.816155
3       0.816155
4       0.823135
5       0.884455
6       0.889115
7       0.925075
8       1.000145
8       1.000145
9       0.999605
10      0.994235
11      1.060795
12      1.066585
13      1.134555
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works perfectly.